# onepage checkout payment method automatically changed and coming by default saved cc?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, payment

Anyone can help me my onepage checkout payment method automatically change, and coming saved cc but it is disabled at backend and rightnow current method is payumoney. Please help me out this problem.

Comment: give us more detail and Provide screenshot Or code Or more deatil with your question

Comment: have check by changing scope?

Comment: @AshishMadankar I have add only product not change any configuration but still my two payment method payumoney and ccavenu not coming.

Comment: Navigate to System->configuration.Try changing Current Configuration Scope: to your web site and check for methods status. hav u check this?

Comment: Yes i have checked it. here is my two payment method payumoney and ccavenue but they r currently not showing at frontend.

Comment: @AshishMadankar I have already done it.

Comment: @AshishMadankar  I haven't get solution.

Comment: @murtuza  I haven't get solution.

Comment: It Might be possible that any extension causing issue. as I dont know about your side Why this kind of strange behavior , I think no one can answer your question because its not contain any specific thing

Comment: @murtuza last10 months site running correctly but this issue comes last 2-3 days ago i have checked all code but not find the issue, i have used magento template path hint and check its block or modal code but i can't get issue. Please help me.

Comment: If its working from last 10months and not working from last 4-5 days then you have done some changes . otherwise its not going to break

Comment: @murtuza I have upload only products nothing with configuration.

Comment: This is not slandered magento problem so that is why no one is able to answer, And by the way how you upload the products?

Comment: @murtuza import csv but i have upload in many times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44338/discussion-between-chirayu-vyas-and-murtuza).

Comment: I also had the same issue and now been solved by these simple steps. Just check or any miscellaneous scripts in head section. If found any encripted script, then Go to ->System-> Configuration-> Design ->HTML Head->Miscellaneous Scripts And delete all this script content.(Note take a backup of full site before performing deletion). Save all the changes and done...